# Why does android.os.binderproxy call onPause in my Application?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, opengl-es, onpause

I have an Android Game, which runs nearly fine. The Game runs with OpenGL ES 2.0 on my Samsung Galaxy Note III (Android 5.0). Some of my testers have HTC devices and they also notice this problem.

The OpengGL-Context gets lost sometimes and onSurfaceCreated gets called. All textures are released and the complete other stuff in onPause has excuted. This happens while playing the game! I cant find a reason for that! Normaly this happen, when the user "minimize" the app or lock his phone, but at my case it happs while looking on the screen. I happens completely randomly! Other testers of my app also notice these problems...

I have noticed that this happens, when the following line logs:

```
03-25 18:43:14.831 23233 23233 I Timeline com.package.name Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2f6edff6 time: 109794643
```

Why does the intent "android.os.BinderProxy" makes my Game idle?
I have no code, which do sth. with proxy or other stuff concerning this intent.

The Start always happens like the following, but the Timeline Log logs also later sometimes:

> 1. onCreate
> 2. onResume
> 3. onSurfaceCreated
> 4. onWindowFocusChanged
> 5. Timeline com.package.name Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2f6edff6 time: 109794643
> 6. onSurfaceChanged

Where is onStop!?

If some code of my application is necessary for the answer please write me!

Here is my latest build of my app:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/amr468mw14c9e6u/FlyEngine.apk?dl=0

Comment: Hi did you get the solutions?

Comment: Hi i still have no idea why it happens. The 'solution' actually is to flag the complete onSurfaceChanged function:"if(bEnter) { bEnter = false; //... "